# Restrict user entering more decimals than in Numerictextbox's configuration

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to restrict users decimal inputs when configured as decimals in `Numerictextbox`. I'm using knockoutjs to observe the data from numerictextbox. When the user enters more decimal it's automatically updated in knockout, but in control it shows only the configured decimals.

Decimals are set dynamically to kendo numerictextbox, so I need to restrict user input decimals when its more of defined decimals. When user enter in a number of decimals knockout updates that value

One example is if I set decimals to 2. When the user enters `56.2456` knockout updates this value in the model, and after the cursor moves to the next control numerictextbox shows `56.25`. I want to update this value into the model and need to restrict user entering more then 2 decimals.

How can I apply this restriction?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: i dont know wt to do.. i googled this but i didnt get anything as  a solution..

Answer (score 1):

You can do key press event of Text box as code below.

```
    $("#txtXZY").kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: "#.00 \\%",
    min: 0,
    decimals: 2,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
    spinners: IsSpinner
});


$("#txtXZY").bind("keypress", function (e) {

    if (IsTextSelected(this) == false && e.keyCode !== kendo.keys.ENTER) {
        var character = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
        var newValue = this.value + character;
        if (isNaN(newValue) || parseFloat(newValue) * 100 % 1 > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        if (parseFloat(newValue) > 100) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
});

function IsTextSelected(input) {
if (typeof input.selectionStart == "number") {
    return input.selectionStart == 0 && input.selectionEnd == input.value.length;
} else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
    input.focus();
    return document.selection.createRange().text == input.value;
}
}
```